# Why does TypeScript not narrow the any-type in this type guard?

Tags: typescript

The following example confuse me:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyProp = "";
}

var object: any = null;

if (object instanceof MyClass)
    console.log(object.MyProp, object.NonExistant); // <-- No error, no intellisense
```

Why isn't the type guard giving me the correct type within the checked context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[User-defined type guards](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1007) and [`instanceof` type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#instanceof-type-guards) does not narrow types that are `any` (including [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#union-types) and [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types) types with `any`) .

The only thing that will narrow an `any` in a type guard is using the `typeof` check and checking for the primitive `string`, `bool`, and `number`:

```
var something: any;
if (typeof something === "string")
{
    something.NonExistant(); // <- Error, does not exist on `string`
    something.substr(0, 10); // <- Ok
}
```

The other generic typeof values, `function`, `object` and `undefined`, does not narrow `any` if one would try to use them like the above example.

There is also an [open issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6015) for making it possible to narrow `any` to primitives within user-defined type guards, milestoned at TS 2.0.

**This is a conscious [design decision](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1426) and not a bug**

The primary motivation seems to have been that type-guarding a type is generally narrowing the possible type and we get access to more properties that we can be sure exists within the checked context. But in the case with type-guarding the special `any`, we already have access to all members that could possibly exists, so doing type-guarding on an `any` as like you expected in your example would actually limit us.

Another motivation also seems to be that there is [too much crappy code](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1938#issuecomment-72994925) out there that would break if TypeScript narrowed `any`'s just like the other types.

**Workaround**

If you have a variable that can be an instance of an arbitrary class, use the type `Object` instead of `any`and type guarding will work as expected.