# User defined type guards don't work with `any` type?

Tags: types, typescript

If I am writing a user defined type guard such as the following:

```
interface Cat {
  meow: () => void;
}

function isCat(a: any): a is Cat {
  return a.name === 'kitty';
}

var x: Cat|{};
if(isCat(x)) {
  x.meow(); // OK, x is Cat in this block
}
```

Typescript is able to figure out the type of `x` within the `if` block above.

[image]

However, if I change the code to:

```
var x; // No type here. It's an "any" for now.
if(isCat(x)) {
  x.meow(); // What!? It's type `any`??
}
```

Typescript assumes that `x` is `any`, even within the "safety" of a type guard `if` statement.

[image]

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940687/why-does-typescript-not-narrow-the-any-type-in-this-type-guard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Verified bug. Reported here already : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6015

Comment: Thanks for the heads up (and everything else you do for TS :-P).