# Type guard does not apply when testing equality with literal OR equality with typeof in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typeguards

In the following code, in the `if` block, `value` is inferred to have type `any` when I expect it to have type `undefined | string`.

```
function stringOrUndefined(value: any): string | undefined {
    if (value === undefined || typeof value === 'string')
        return value // value is any
    throw TypeError()
}
```

If I replace the `value === undefined` test by `typeof value === 'undefined'`, I get the expected type inference:

```
function stringOrUndefined(value: any): string | undefined {
    if (typeof value === 'undefined' || typeof value === 'string')
        return value // value is string | undefined
    throw TypeError()
}
```

Is the flow analysis not capable of handling ORing a typeguard based on a literal check and a typeguard based on a `typeof` check?

I am using Typescript v3.8.3. The behaviour can be seen [on the Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZygJxmA5geTQVTABMBTYTEogCgDcBDAGxBIC5E6wBPASjdQ2yIAPonClyYSogDeAKEQLEMYIipROABxJwV9JiUQBeY4gDkYshSKnhI9Vp2I9zIydP9MWU90RoSUEDQkZxJ5RSgACzQ4AHdEABVNEgBRNGi0Km5ZAF9ZWVBIWAQUdE88QnErACZaRmY2Dh4+UsERCwkpOUUlFTUkxxDXQzN2qxshO37dOoNjYfcWrx8-AKCnGbCFSOi4xK1U9MycoA).

Comment: looks like value type guards for `any` are not applied, its not about the `||` but about `any`. check this - https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgLnmAnjAvDAjAbgFB4CWAZjABRQoAOApiKXBupgORgCuAtgEY0BOLAJQwA3nhjwYAeikxCEGBx788AXyKkyjZpizCxExjLkK4qGAFpFIGDWLEawKGoLH2YQuDmQoNOABMYemQUPFAfGG4kJV4+GAAfGGg+QjAAcwxseAUY-gSkqBT0ghJybiZdfXFI6Vly+Ww1IA

Comment: @MaciejSikora looks like you are onto something: replacing `any` with `unknown` makes the  inference work. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=18&ssc=11&pln=18&pc=26#code/PTAEEMDsE8CgGMD2kDOAXCAuCNQF5QBGAbllgEsAzUACjWgAcBTRa8fPAgckgFcBbAEZMATlwCUoAN6xQEUCFDkUoPkNGwAvhWo12nAoUky57RcpzRQAWlWJQTSpSbw0Wsot6QA1pEQB3SARkdFB4bC9fAMh8IlIdWnpmVjCObjVhMWNZVPMVDI1tKlp4NKJsuVK8ondYT0hyZCVUNCZwABNQFKg4JBbQQWwCkVAAH1B0EXJIAHNYwgh8gUyxibQp2bJimkEyo2kc3cVdi0ItIA

Comment: Here more info - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940687/why-does-typescript-not-narrow-the-any-type-in-this-type-guard

Answer (score 0):

According to the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36940687/why-does-typescript-not-narrow-the-any-type-in-this-type-guard), “primitive” type guards can only add methods and attributes to a type. Given that `any` already has all the methods and attributes it does not make sense to narrow it in this fashion.

Type guards involving `typeof` with `'string'`, `'bool'` or `'number'` are a special case.